# Azure Function Updating user profile using SharePoint Online and CSOM .NET Standard gives access denied

Tags: c#, azure-functions, sharepoint-online, csom, .net-standard-2.0

I have Azure Function v3 and I want to update Sharepoint user profile properties with CSOM and .NET standard 2.0 by using global admin account credentials. Reading is working.

```
        var site = new Uri("https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com");
        using (var authenticationManager = new AuthenticationManager())
        using (var context = authenticationManager.GetContext(site, user, password))
        {
            var peopleManager = new PeopleManager(context);

            var personProperties = peopleManager.GetPropertiesFor(accountName);
            context.Load(personProperties, p => p.AccountName, p => p.UserProfileProperties);
            await context.ExecuteQueryAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(personProperties.UserProfileProperties["FirstName"]); //works
            peopleManager.SetSingleValueProfileProperty(personProperties.AccountName, "FirstName", "CSOMvalue");
            await context.ExecuteQueryAsync(); //error, access denied
        }
```

Exact Error message: System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: FunctionName. Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.

AuthenticationManager class is taken from MS docs from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/using-csom-for-dotnet-standard)
Im using Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM v16.1.20518.12000 nuget package.

I made .NET Framework 4.7.2 web app and it worked using SharePointOnlineCredentials. But I want to know how to get it working on .NET Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

From my past experience and couple of hours research :

When you use Azure AD Application, you can read through the User Profiles - but not perform CSOM write operation.

**reference :**
[image]

Though the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly#what-are-the-limitations-when-using-app-only) says it is applicable for using app-only, this behavior has been observed Azure AD Application in general (user + app as well)  - hence the reason why you are able to read but however not write.

As mentioned in the article you will have to the **Sharepoint App only** context and perform a read/write operation.

```
context = new AuthenticationManager().GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, "[Your Client ID]", "[Your Client Secret]")
```

Here the authenticationmanager is of the SharepointPNPcoreOnline library.

[image]

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs) details the same.

If you want the user context while performing the same (not usually required because you re performing at the UPA ) - you can create the app accordingly - but really not sure whether the SharepointPNPCOreOnline supports this.